# I can't get rid of the extra matches in my regex

Tags: python, regex

I am new with python and I am trying to extract only the dates from a text file but when I match them this is the result. Can I get help with how to get rid of these ?
my code:

```
import re


file1 = open('wireshark.txt', 'r')

for line in file1:
    regex = re.match(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", line)
    marks = re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", line)
    print(regex, marks)
```

Code execution output:

```
None [] None ['2021-02-12'] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None ['2021-02-12'] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None [] None ['2021-02-12'] None [] None [] None ['2021-02-12']
```

`wireshark.txt`:

```
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 2021-02-12 13:33:12.206424    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         QUIC     1392   Initial, DCID=e4267bae554f387d, PKN: 1, CRYPTO, PADDING

Frame 2: 1392 bytes on wire (11136 bits), 1392 bytes captured (11136 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{28AA034F-AC94-4D4A-9CA9-9AEA5D0EF2C1}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Micro-St_0e:cd:34 (00:d8:61:0e:cd:34), Dst: Verizon_fb:8b:82 (20:c0:47:fb:8b:82)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.151, Dst: 172.217.10.46
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 57189, Dst Port: 443
QUIC IETF

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 2021-02-12 13:33:12.225610    172.217.10.46         192.168.1.151         QUIC     1392   Initial, SCID=e4267bae554f387d, PKN: 1, ACK, CRYPTO, PADDING

Frame 3: 1392 bytes on wire (11136 bits), 1392 bytes captured (11136 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{28AA034F-AC94-4D4A-9CA9-9AEA5D0EF2C1}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Verizon_fb:8b:82 (20:c0:47:fb:8b:82), Dst: Micro-St_0e:cd:34 (00:d8:61:0e:cd:34)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.217.10.46, Dst: 192.168.1.151
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 57189
QUIC IETF

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2021-02-12 13:33:12.225989    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  146    Application Data

Frame 4: 146 bytes on wire (1168 bits), 146 bytes captured (1168 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{28AA034F-AC94-4D4A-9CA9-9AEA5D0EF2C1}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Micro-St_0e:cd:34 (00:d8:61:0e:cd:34), Dst: Verizon_fb:8b:82 (20:c0:47:fb:8b:82)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.151, Dst: 172.217.10.46
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 59112, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 92
Transport Layer Security

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 2021-02-12 13:33:12.226126    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  85     Application Data
```

Desired code execute output:

```
['2021-02-12']
['2021-02-13']
['2021-02-14']
```

Comment: Please add an example of what the text looks like in `wireshark.txt` for people to be able to help you with your regular expression. We have no idea what the text looks like in this file.

Comment: No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2021-02-12 13:33:12.225989    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  146    Application Data, 

It's like this but if moves on to more

Comment: @duynguyen Update your question with it and not as a comment

Comment: Lmfao "no." You need to provide this in your question, not the comments. Provide a snip it of the text instead of explaining it. If you expect an answer, then please provide all the details to the question.

Comment: is this better? lmao I am new at this. Sorry

Comment: `re.match` checks only at the beginning of the string. Since no line starts with a date, it always produces `None` (no match), in this case.

Comment: What outcome are you looking for, exactly? Could you edit in what you want to get as a result from that file?

Comment: I'm looking for an outcome somewhat to that.

Comment: Try removing `regex` part, and only printing `marks` if it is not empty.

Comment: @duynguyen Please accept an answer below if it matches what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A few hopefully helpful suggestions:

You have:

```py
regex = re.match(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", line)
```

First of all, `re.match` will only return a match that occurs at the beginning of the string, `line`. If you wanted to find that pattern anywhere within the string, then you should use method `re.search` instead. Second, `re.match` returns a "match object" or `None` depending upon whether the match succeeded or not. It does *not* return a regular expression. So naming the variable to hold the result "regex" was perhaps not the best choice.

Second, as mentioned by @FricativeMelon, if you are processing the input file line by line looking for *all* the matches on the line using `re.findall`, there is little point to also looking for a match that is at the first character position of the line. And you don't want to print out an empty list when no matches are found on the line. These changes result in the following code:

```py
import re


file1 = open('wireshark.txt', 'r')

for line in file1:
    marks = re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", line)
    if marks: # equivalent to either (1) if len(marks): (2) if len(marks) != 0:
        print(marks)

file1.close()
```

Note that I also added an extra statement to close the opened file when we are through reading it.

You can also read in the entire file and do one search:

```py
import re


with open('wireshark.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
# the file is automatically closed now
marks = re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", text)
print(marks) # show what we found, even if it is nothing
```

One final point:

Your regular expression will also find matches within strings such as `11111-11-11` and `1111-11-111`. If you want to make sure that your match is not preceded and followed by *additional digits*, then modify the regular expression to use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead assertion:

```
(?<!\d)\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d(?!\d)
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p31jpn/1/)